# Anchor link structured website & SEO

Tags: seo, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to SEO a Single-Page website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23169/how-to-seo-a-single-page-website)

My client wants to have a website similar to [this](http://www.42angels.com/) one. I think that this concept could really work well as a simple presentation of business portfolio but I can't figure out how good I could optimize website for search engines because all content is actually on one single (long) page.

Do you have any suggestions concerning this specific case? I guess google would only index one page?

Answer (score 1):

A one page website like this isn't great for SEO (Google only index 1 page like you say).  I'm not aware of a way to have anchor links indexed as separate pages either (happy to be corrected if someone else out there knows of a way).  That said, with the site you have shown, the page content for each section is pretty light on - so I don't think there would be a great deal of SEO benefit to splitting it up into different URLs anyway.

My recommendation would be to have a Blog as a different section on the site.  If your client is serious about SEO, they will need to give their content strategy some thought and get writing (or hire a copywriter).