# How to improve a single-paged site search result

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to SEO a Single-Page website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23169/how-to-seo-a-single-page-website)

I created an online CV of mine a couple of weeks ago and it has had quite a few visits. Now I want to improve the chance it will appear in google search results; however, my web CV is a one-paged site and it contains only internal links (those with hash #) so I can't really submit a sitemap.

I could have changed the internal links to normal links to be processed on server-side, but there's no point of doing so.

I'm very new to web SEO so I would really appreciate if somebody can show me what should I do with a single-paged site with internal links to be effectively indexed by crawlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically this is a fundamental problem with one page websites.

- Add properly structured links rather than hashbangs
- Use a domain that contains your first name and surname.
- Add text content and alt tags don't make the main focus images.

Outside of the website

- Ensure the site links to all of your social media accounts,
  especially linkedin.
- Join linkedin groups relevent to your profession.
- Ensure your linked in profile is public.
- Submit the site to CSS and professional galleries.

This should be enough to get Google to rank it for your name inside your own country/region. If it so happens you have a common name, or your name is competitive in Google's ranking consider using a professional name or adding your middle name into the domain and social media mix and possibly building a multi-page site.

Comment: My thread is closed due to a possible duplicate, but thanks for answering me though :) +1

Comment: @Trisism no problem, you should read JohnConde's answer to the other question too - he has enormous SEO experience.

Answer (score 1):

Internal links ([fragments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)) [aren't crawled by search engine spiders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001433/does-google-ignores-whatever-is-after-the-hash-fragment-while-crawling-our-w). So unless you're using Ajax to load additional content then you need to reconsider your approach.

If you are using AJAX, then [Google's escape_fragment method is ok](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992) (even though it's considered obsolete in light of [HTML5's 'pushstate' method](http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate)).

If you're using one of those JS/CSS single-page templates that hides content in DIVs and toggles them, then you don't need to worry about all of this as Google can see all of the content. You'll just need to build backlinks.