# One page website SEO - Can Google show multiple entries that jump to the relevant section?

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to SEO a Single-Page website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23169/how-to-seo-a-single-page-website)

A client wants a content-heavy one page Wordpress website, with scroll-to navigation. And they want it search engine optimised :)

I thought that if Google could see each section as a page, with unique title, I might be able to achieve all of the above.

I came across [this article](http://www.2bscene.ie/blog/2011/12/web-design-creating-a-search-engine-friendly-one-page-website-with-jquery/), which suggests creating multiple pages for Google, but then hijacking the navigation links with Ajax to load the content within the single page for the human visitor.

It would be great if I could get some advice on whether or not this is madness!

***EDIT***

Perhaps my question is too subjective or ambiguous...

What I would really like to know is: *Are there any potential negative impacts in terms of SEO, Google ranking, page load speed (apart from the obvious effect of having all content on one page) or whatever to using this method?*

Thanks!

Comment: Hi John, thanks for taking a look at my question. However I do not agree that it is an exact duplicate, as the answer to the other question does not answer my question. I wish to know if having multiple pages for Google but pulling in the content with Ajax for human visitors would actually 'fool' Google, or potentially have me penalised.